# Regex for repeating pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex which satisfies the following conditions.
1. Total length of string 300 characters.
2. Should start with `&,-,/,#` only followed by `3 or 4 alphanumeric characters`
3. This above pattern can be in continuous string upto `300 characters`

String example - &ACK2-ASD3#RERT...

I have tried repeating the group but unsuccessful.

```
(^[&//-#][A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})+
```

That is not working ..just matches the first set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may validate the string first using `/^(?:[&\/#-][A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})+$/` regex and checking the string length (using `s.length <= 300`) and then return all matches with a part of the validation regex:

```js
var s = "&ACK2-ASD3#RERT";
var val_rx = /^(?:[&\/#-][A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})+$/;
if (val_rx.test(s) && s.length <= 300) {
  console.log(s.match(/[&\/#-][A-Za-z0-9]{3,4}/g));
}
```

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[&\/#-][A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `[&\/#-]` -  `&`, `/`, `#` or `-`
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4}` - three or four alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vFZdXo/1).

Note the absence of `g` modifier with the validation regex used with `RegExp#test` and it must be present in the extraction regex (as we need to check the string only once, but extract multiple occurrences).

Answer (score 2):

You're close. Add the lookahead: `(?=.{0,300}$)` to the start to make it satisfy the length requirement and do it with pure RegExp:

```
/(?=.{0,300}$)^([&\-#][A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})+$/.test("&ACK2-ASD3#RERT")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/9xnrcE/2).

```js
const regex = /^([&\/\-#][A-Za-z0-9]{3,4}){0,300}$/g;
const str = `&ACK2-ASD3#RERT`;
if (regex.test(str)) {
    console.log("Match");
}
```